# Can a Chrome Extension create popups?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating Chrome Extensions, so please excuse if I'm missing something obvious.

Is it possible to have a chrome extension create pop-ups such as those shown on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#popovers)?

It didn't seem possible from what I was reading on the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chrome Extensions can do anything "normal" web pages can do (and more). There are other types of popups that only extensions can do, but that does not seem to be what you're asking.